# Get the selected text from text input

Tags: android, wysiwyg, rich-text-editor, react-native

Suppose this is a component

```
class Wysiwyg extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <View>
                <TextInput placeholder="Type here" />
            </View>
        )
    }    
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => Wysiwyg)
```

And I typed: "Big brown eyes!"

Now if I selected "Big" from the text input. How do I get the selected text input value so that I can change the "Big" into **Big** bold on pressing a button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by utilising onSelectionChange and onChangeText props of TextInput:

```
export default class TextSelectionTest extends Component {

  state = {
    selection: [0,0],
    text: ''
  };

  render() {
    const {selection: [start, end], text} = this.state;
    const selected = text.substring(start, end);
    return (
      <View>
        <TextInput value={text} onSelectionChange={this.onSelectionChange} 
                   onChangeText={text => this.setState({text})}/>
        <Text>{`Selected chars ${start}-${end}: ${selected}`}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  onSelectionChange = event => {
    const selection = event.nativeEvent.selection;
    this.setState({
      selection: [selection.start, selection.end]
    });
  };
}
```

As for making selection bold, I think react-native TextInput currently does not have rich text editor capabilities, so it is not possible.

Comment: I will check and get back to you soon. Thank you.

Comment: Since React Native 0.60 `onSelectionChange` requires `multiline={true}`. I'm guessing this is the culprit: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21515